# Looking to add data to a named excel table using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to add data to a named table in excel, but I don't know how to add additional rows to a named excel table as the openpyxl documentation is not helpful on what this package does. The best I have been able to do so far, which has not worked, is the following:

```py
test = load_workbook(r'\\data4\users2\wyoung3\My Documents\Test.xlsx')
twb = test['Sheet2']
twbs = twb._tables
twbs = twbs.append(['s']) #this was my attempt to try and append an item to the bottom of the list
test.save(r'\\data4\users2\wyoung3\My Documents\Test.xlsx')
```

This resulted in a file that I could not open and the error message:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tableColumns'

Can anyone advise on how I can go about addressing this problem?

Comment: Do you mind to read [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and about [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have read the documents and am not clear on what further information you require?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible.

Comment: Ok, excepting that point, do you know of a way to add additional rows to a named table in Python?

Comment: If you use pandas, and you should if you are working with table, you can use pandas.concat

Comment: Your code makes no sense: `'s'` is not a table object.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking is not very clear, so I will provide a few options. The [tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) for `openpyxl` is actually decent, so you should try going through it.

First, using [Tables](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet_tables.html):

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableStyleInfo

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

data = [
    ['Apples', 10000, 5000, 8000, 6000],
    ['Pears',   2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
    ['Bananas', 6000, 6000, 6500, 6000],
    ['Oranges',  500,  300,  200,  700],
]

# add column headings. NB. these must be strings
ws.append(["Fruit", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"])
for row in data:
    ws.append(row)

tab = Table(displayName="Table1", ref="A1:E5")

# Add a default style with striped rows and banded columns
style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium9", showFirstColumn=False,
                       showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=True)
tab.tableStyleInfo = style
ws.add_table(tab)
wb.save("table.xlsx")
```

Alternatively, if you know the cell location already, you can simply `insert_rows()`.

> The default is one row or column. For example to insert a row at 7 (before the existing row 7):

```py
ws.insert_rows(7)
```

Comment: Ok, just to clarify. The table I have already exists. If I try to do an insert rows on the table object, python tells me that insert_rows is not an attribute that is had by table objects.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping my solution here because I had the same problem and can't find a better posed question.. though I think the answers you got were snobby because it looks like you didn't really get even close enough for good code critique :(

My solution is clunky, unfortunately. Basically refer to defined tables range with openpyxl to write data field by field, record by record, to a new table in memory, delete the old table from the sheet formatting, and redefine the now enlarged area as a table again.

The code sample below needs predefined file name as flNm, sheet name as shNm, table name as tblNm and data to add to table as a list of lists where sublist is one new row. Please note i imported openpyxl as pyxl.In my testing I was doing a table with 7 fields so there are 7 digits in a sublist. Works for 1 or more rows. Assumes that your excel table has pre existing data you dont want to overwrite. In case of new blank table with 1 empty row, won't fill that in first.

```
wb=pyxl.load_workbook(flNm)
ws=wb[shNm]
t=ws.tables[tblNm]
ref=t.ref
row,col=ws[ref[ref.index(':')+1:]].row,ws[ref[:ref.index(':')]].column
records=[[0,1,0,1,0,1,0]]
for rec in records:
    for i in range(len(rec)):
        ws.cell(column=col+i,row=row+records.index(rec)+1).value=rec[i]
newT=pyxl.worksheet.table.Table(displayName=t.displayName,ref=t.ref[:-len(str(row))]+str(row+len(records)))
style = pyxl.worksheet.table.TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleLight1",showRowStripes=True)
newT.tableStyleInfo = style
del ws.tables[shNm]
ws.add_table(newT)
wb.save(filename=flNm)
```